# Closing second level show dialog popup window asp.net c# and js

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

There are two show dialog windows that are opened in button click within as a part of requirement.

1. main.aspx opens a show dialog on a button click code behind as follows:

   ```
    string script = "var popup1= window.showModalDialog('../modalframe.htm', 'attendees.aspx', 'options')";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Attendee", script, true);
   ```
2. attendees.aspx opens another showdialog window on its button click

   ```
    string script = "var popup2= window.showModalDialog('../modalframe.htm', 'map.aspx', 'options')";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Map", script, true);
   ```

In a button click of map.aspx I need to close both popup windows and return to main.aspx. I tried the following: It works for the current window(popup2). How can I close popup1?

```
 protected void btn_Return_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>window.returnValue = 1; window.parent.window.close(); </script>");

}
```

Comment: Any reason why you are not using javascript for this?

Comment: They are all existing modules and I can not change it. This is also a part of js. You are welcome with your own ideas.